# Interpolation of an upper-triangular list

Tags: interpolation

I have 2d list which is upper triangular. I would like to interpolate it, but I cannot unless I set the interpolation order to 1. I tried making the list rectangular by filling the bottom half with `Null`. This does allow me to interpolate with higher order. However, the interpolation function ends too early; that is, it does not return values when the distance from the boundary (the diagonal elements of the list) is relatively small. I would like to have a full interpolation up to (or very close to) the boundary. any advice?

Here is the list that I would like to interpolate.

```
{{0.103974, 0.103971, 0.103953, 0.103899, 0.103786, 0.103597, 
  0.103316, 0.102925, 0.102414, 0.10177, 0.100988, 0.100062, 
  0.0989872, 0.0977656, 0.0963984, 0.09489, 0.0932473, 0.0914792, 
  0.089597, 0.0876143, 0.0855483, 0.0834163, 0.0812392, 0.0790409, 
  0.0768409, 0.0746749, 0.0725479, 0.0703533, 0.068163, 
  0.0666494}, {0.10394, 0.103939, 0.103922, 0.103868, 0.103755, 
  0.103567, 0.103285, 0.102896, 0.102385, 0.101742, 0.10096, 0.100033,
   0.0989584, 0.0977364, 0.0963682, 0.0948584, 0.093214, 0.0914444, 
  0.0895606, 0.087576, 0.0855068, 0.0833692, 0.0811831, 0.0789712, 
  0.0767541, 0.0745556, 0.0723645, 0.0701298, 0.0680141}, {0.10387, 
  0.103868, 0.10385, 0.103795, 0.103683, 0.103495, 0.103214, 0.102825,
   0.102314, 0.10167, 0.100887, 0.0999592, 0.0988834, 0.0976591, 
  0.0962884, 0.0947757, 0.0931276, 0.091353, 0.0894624, 0.0874687, 
  0.0853863, 0.0832311, 0.0810217, 0.0787762, 0.076513, 0.0742205, 
  0.0718546, 0.0695221}, {0.103748, 0.103745, 0.103724, 0.103669, 
  0.103558, 0.103371, 0.10309, 0.102699, 0.102187, 0.101542, 0.100757,
   0.0998263, 0.0987467, 0.0975176, 0.0961414, 0.0946217, 0.0929642, 
  0.0911773, 0.089271, 0.0872567, 0.0851463, 0.0829572, 0.0807012, 
  0.0783843, 0.0760088, 0.0734579, 0.0706321}, {0.103554, 0.103551, 
  0.103531, 0.103476, 0.103366, 0.103178, 0.102896, 0.102504, 
  0.101989, 0.101341, 0.100553, 0.099617, 0.0985308, 0.0972933, 
  0.0959062, 0.0943723, 0.0926975, 0.0908894, 0.0889562, 0.0869069, 
  0.0847519, 0.0825056, 0.0801589, 0.0777, 0.0750337, 
  0.0716811}, {0.103276, 0.103275, 0.103256, 0.103202, 0.10309, 
  0.102901, 0.102618, 0.102223, 0.101704, 0.101052, 0.100256, 
  0.0993117, 0.0982145, 0.0969632, 0.0955586, 0.0940032, 0.092303, 
  0.0904624, 0.0884869, 0.0863832, 0.0841579, 0.081807, 0.0792933, 
  0.0765284, 0.0728391}, {0.102903, 0.102902, 0.102884, 0.10283, 
  0.102718, 0.102528, 0.102241, 0.101843, 0.101318, 0.100658, 
  0.0998522, 0.0988945, 0.0977811, 0.0965098, 0.0950807, 0.0934955, 
  0.0917577, 0.0898677, 0.0878288, 0.0856427, 0.0832993, 0.0807647, 
  0.0779256, 0.0740117}, {0.102422, 0.102422, 0.102405, 0.10235, 
  0.102237, 0.102044, 0.101754, 0.101349, 0.100817, 0.100146, 
  0.0993255, 0.09835, 0.0972144, 0.0959158, 0.0944531, 0.0928257, 
  0.091033, 0.089073, 0.0869434, 0.0846283, 0.0820913, 0.0792068, 
  0.0751356}, {0.101822, 0.101823, 0.101806, 0.101752, 0.101637, 
  0.10144, 0.101144, 0.100732, 0.100188, 0.099502, 0.0986628, 
  0.097664, 0.0964989, 0.0951639, 0.0936555, 0.0919695, 0.090102, 
  0.0880447, 0.0857767, 0.083259, 0.0803534, 0.0761756}, {0.101097, 
  0.101098, 0.101081, 0.101026, 0.100909, 0.100708, 0.100405, 
  0.0999814, 0.0994228, 0.0987171, 0.0978542, 0.0968249, 0.0956215, 
  0.0942383, 0.0926684, 0.090904, 0.0889336, 0.0867302, 0.0842497, 
  0.0813519, 0.0771066}, {0.100239, 0.10024, 0.100224, 0.100167, 
  0.100048, 0.0998402, 0.0995268, 0.0990894, 0.0985123, 0.0977829, 
  0.0968891, 0.0958205, 0.0945678, 0.0931211, 0.0914701, 0.0895987, 
  0.0874762, 0.0850528, 0.0821852, 0.0779089}, {0.0992445, 0.0992461, 
  0.0992294, 0.0991719, 0.099048, 0.0988324, 0.0985062, 0.0980515, 
  0.0974514, 0.0966918, 0.0957588, 0.0946403, 0.0933235, 0.0917941, 
  0.0900337, 0.0880059, 0.0856582, 0.0828417, 0.0785649}, {0.0981125, 
  0.0981144, 0.0980973, 0.0980374, 0.0979076, 0.0976814, 0.09734, 
  0.096864, 0.0962348, 0.0954372, 0.0944552, 0.093273, 0.0918731, 
  0.0902326, 0.0883131, 0.0860581, 0.0833127, 0.0790662}, {0.0968426, 
  0.0968454, 0.096828, 0.0967645, 0.0966264, 0.0963876, 0.0960279, 
  0.0955252, 0.0948597, 0.0940148, 0.0929701, 0.0917054, 0.0901945, 
  0.0883946, 0.0862476, 0.0835918, 0.079405}, {0.0954383, 0.0954419, 
  0.095424, 0.0953556, 0.0952077, 0.0949537, 0.0945706, 0.0940344, 
  0.0933241, 0.0924188, 0.0912934, 0.0899197, 0.0882514, 0.0862242, 
  0.083675, 0.0795756}, {0.0939058, 0.0939098, 0.09389, 0.0938154, 
  0.0936557, 0.093382, 0.092969, 0.0923913, 0.0916245, 0.0906417, 
  0.0894103, 0.0878829, 0.0859885, 0.0835615, 0.0795752}, {0.0922516, 
  0.0922556, 0.0922334, 0.092151, 0.0919761, 0.0916776, 0.0912276, 
  0.0905977, 0.0897577, 0.088673, 0.0872931, 0.0855428, 0.0832538, 
  0.0794039}, {0.0904849, 0.0904886, 0.0904629, 0.0903703, 0.090176, 
  0.0898463, 0.0893496, 0.0886522, 0.0877159, 0.0864893, 0.0848929, 
  0.0827551, 0.0790643}, {0.0886172, 0.0886199, 0.0885891, 0.0884833, 
  0.0882643, 0.0878948, 0.0873377, 0.0865514, 0.0854815, 0.0840469, 
  0.0820716, 0.078562}, {0.08666, 0.086662, 0.0866252, 0.086502, 
  0.0862506, 0.0858294, 0.0851927, 0.0842826, 0.0830158, 0.0812123, 
  0.0779048}, {0.0846302, 0.0846316, 0.0845855, 0.0844381, 0.084145, 
  0.0836566, 0.0829073, 0.0818115, 0.0801893, 0.0771012}, {0.0825462, 
  0.0825452, 0.082486, 0.0823086, 0.0819616, 0.081374, 0.0804515, 
  0.0790206, 0.0761684}, {0.0804289, 0.0804223, 0.0803448, 0.0801253, 
  0.0796932, 0.0789504, 0.0777197, 0.0751256}, {0.0783023, 0.078285, 
  0.0781783, 0.0778938, 0.0773324, 0.0763055, 0.0739972}, {0.0761874, 
  0.0761545, 0.0760065, 0.0756224, 0.074797, 0.0728167}, {0.0741274, 
  0.0740638, 0.0738307, 0.0732125, 0.0716426}, {0.0721374, 0.0720111, 
  0.071612, 0.0705599}, {0.0701032, 0.0699286, 0.0694193}, {0.0680611,
   0.0679384}, {0.0666374}}
```

and here is the code I am using

```
temp1 = ConstantArray[Null, {30, 30}]; 
Table[temp1[[ixa, ixb]] = data[[ixa, ixb]], {ixa, Range[1, 30]}, {ixb, 30 - ixa + 1}]; 
F = ListInterpolation[temp1, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Comment: I'd like to see your interpolation code

Comment: temp1 = ConstantArray[Null, {30, 30}];

Table[
  temp1[[ixa, ixb]] = data[[ixa, ixb]]
  , {ixa, Range[1, 30]}, {ixb, 30 - ixa + 1}];


F = ListInterpolation[temp1, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]

Comment: Please do not convey your code in a comment. Always add to your question by editing the question. Because this is first post, I have done it for you.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting numerical problems with polynomial interpolation because of the effectively discontinuous jump in function values at the diagonal, if you insist on padding the missing triangle with zeros.

To get a good interpolation, you should simply pad the matrix in such a way as to avoid a numerical discontinuity. Here is how I would do that:

Call the list in your example `a`, then define

```
b = PadLeft[#, Length[First[a]], First[#]] & /@ a;
ListPlot3D[b]
```

[image: 3d plot]

Now the diagonal has a continuous transition. The above plot is already an interpolation. To get the interpolation explicitly, we do this:

```
interpol = ListInterpolation[b, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

ContourPlot[interpol[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: interp]

The region near the diagonal is smoothly interpolated.

Comment: It works perfectly. I just had to change PadLeft to PadRight. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the interpolation along row N°10 of your table :

[image]

One see on the first graphic that the end of data are at position 21.

On the other graphics, one see that if you use `InterpolationOrder` superior to 1, the interpolation is smooth until 20.

To go beyond 20 with `InterpolationOrder` superior to 1, you must make some further hypotheses about the
behaviour of the data >21 (value different from 0) or about the derivative of the function at 21 .

If there no such very accurate hypothesis, I think that linear interpolation is the best choice for values between 20 and 21.

Note : Here, it's a interpolation 2D of the full table (not interpolation 1D along row 10 of the table).

Comment: I have done a smooth interpolation of order superior to 1, and at the end, there was not difference.